# HTML: Embedding an autostarted looping slide show

Tags: javascript, html, css, photo

I know there is a way to embed an autostarted looping slide show like this:
http://responsiveslides.com/

But let's say I want to add a new photo to the slide show. That means that I will have to go into the html code and add/delete code linking the image files. I want to just add pictures (could be to a local folder or a web site doesn't matter) and it updates the slide show with the new images. I know you can use flickr.com, but it does not have the autostart or looping features. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmwbLqxq/2/

Stole this from W3 obviously, except added the css to do the silky animation.  All you have to do is add another img tag.

Edit:

In response to what you said, you would have to make a server side database and a 'upload images' button to add images to the database.  When the screen loads, it runs your server side code that queries the database for the images, loops through them and inserts into html.

Comment: Yeah but you still have to add in the: <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%"> using your method if you want to add a new picture. I want to just add a new picture to the web site and not have to worry about updating the html code.